# Dynamic Linq: Select new object of known type

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Consider we have this class which is used for aggregated reports:

```
public class ReportSeriesData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public ReportSeriesData()
    {

    }

    public ReportSeriesData(string Title, double Value)
    {

    }
}
```

I use [Dynamic Linq](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) to group records and then I'd like to select the results into List of ReportSeriesData

```
  var reportData = list.AsQueryable().GroupBy(UserSelectedField, "it").Select("new (it.Key as Title, it.Count() as Value) as ReportSeriesData");
```

The above statement produces an error :

> An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Syntax error

What is the proper way to select object of known type in dynamic linq ?

Comment: Just to know, why do you use Dynamic Linq and not "classic" Linq ? in Linq this kind of query is pretty easy to write - maybe you can even mix them.

Comment: @gobes I use Dynamic Linq because i want to be able to select a field to group by at runtime, moreover the type of source data is also generated at runtime so i can't use classic linq

Answer (score -1):

you can either do this

```
var reportData = from instance in list  
group instance by instance.UserSelectedField into group  
select new ReportSeriesData() with {.Title = group.Key,.Value = group.Count}
```

or

```
  var reportData=list.AsQueryable().GroupBy(UserSelectedField, "it").Select(g => new ReportSeriesData() 
    { 
        Title= g.Key,
        Value= g.Count
    }
```